# Why can a numeric literal be interpreted as an NSNumber in Swift?

Tags: swift, nsnumber

Why is the following piece of code possible in Swift?

```
import Foundation
let n: NSNumber = 35.5
```

NSNumber is a type defined in the Foundation module and is not defined as a native type in Swift. How can the literal of `35.5` be interpreted as a value of NSNumber?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`NSNumber`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsnumber)
conforms to the [`ExpressibleByBooleanLiteral`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/expressiblebybooleanliteral), [`ExpressibleByFloatLiteral`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/expressiblebyfloatliteral)
and [`ExpressibleByIntegerLiteral`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/expressiblebyintegerliteral) protocols, which means that it can be
initialized  from a boolean, floating point, or integer literal:

```
let n1: NSNumber = false
let n2: NSNumber = 12.34
let n3: NSNumber = 123
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a protocol named `ExpressibleByIntegerLiteral`. If your class conforms to that protocol it allows you to init itself using syntax like the one you've shown. There are another protocols like than e.g. `ExpressibleByStringLiteral` that works in a smiliar manner.

NSNumber just conforms to `ExpressibleByIntegerLiteral` protocol which means it implements `init(integerLiteral value: Self.IntegerLiteralType)` which is used in that case.

Answer (score 0):

NsNunber has an inner union holding the data. As such the primitive type can just be assigned. See also https://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2012-07-06-lets-build-nsnumber.html